# Status of the application

Tags: legal-status

In reference to the patent: [US20070257041](https://www.google.com/patents/US20070257041)

Hello
What is the status of this application?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The best place to determine the status of US patents and applications is the [US Public Pair](https://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair) site. In the case of US20070257041, the current status is "Abandoned -- Failure to Respond to an Office Action".  The status date is 10-15-2008 which means the applicant failed to respond to an office action (in this case a non-final rejection) in 2008. While it may be possible to resurrect the application, at this point I'd rather doubt it will happen.